# Is it possible to create a new account type for OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: social-networking, osx-mountain-lion

OSX mountain lion provide a lots of account type including twitter, and many service for China(weibo, tudou and so on). But there no default facebook support for ML, I know I can install it.

My question is, is it possibility to make my own Service (Account or something else) for other website? Is there some APIs that can do such thing?

Comment: Official Facebook support is coming in a patch later this year.

Comment: Who develop this, facebook or apple?